# Chinese speaking and vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary, simplified-characters, spoken, listening, middle-chinese

大家好
Can anybody help with recourses that I can make my speaking and vocabulary better? Is there anybooks that can help me?

Comment: There's a mountain of resources for learning Chinese; too many to list.  Asking about resources for some specific task is usually okay, but such a broad question is not well suited to this site.  Reddit [r/ChineseLanguage](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage) is better suited to everyone-shares-their-methods questions; here we expect questions which are answerable (as in, we can read the answer and say "that's correct").

Answer (score 0):

There are many resource in Youtube. Search for "New HSK Level 1" and you should have many videos with vocab and pronunciation.

Answer (score 0):

You can always go to the website "zhihu.com", among which there are so many native Chinese speakers.